# Unable to perform XMLHttpRequest for get from facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, console

I tried this in console (Google chrome-> press `f12` -> click console)

```
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open( "GET", "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vigneshvdm/5fd850d0fdb292189815/raw/6f3bdb2399b57c5d292b0f002d2f9aec7a87cafd/Image%20path%20for%20facebook", false );
xmlHttp.send( null );
xmlHttp.responseText;
```

If i run this same script in stackoverflow or any other site its returning the value in console

But when i try this in facebook its saying

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Refused to connect to 
'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vigneshvdm/5fd850d0fdb292189815/raw/6f3bdb2399b57c5d292b0f002d2f9aec7a87cafd/Image%20path%20for%20facebook' 
because it violates the document's Content Security Policy.
```

Is it not possible to perform a `http get` in facebook using console?

Comment: Facebook uses [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP) to limit certain features as a precaution against certain attacks.

Comment: is it applicable to all sites served under `https` or only facebook has blocked this?

Comment: No, not all sites over https use CSP. It's an opt-in security feature.

Comment: it is getting the image but its not getting the string !!
imageUrl="url(http://www.coolgraphic.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/01.gif)"; 
if i assign this to backgroundImage its working!!